USB speaker not working after sleep - Best workaround?
After Windows was in sleep mode, my USB speakers stop working.
What I tried:

Disabled selective USB energy saving in the energy options

Workarounds:

Unpluging/repluging the USB cable: works, but is a bit tedious since this happens several times daily
USB Hub with on/off button: works better, but the audio sometimes crackles (probably because of the hub)
Using USB Device Tree Viewer: restarting the device does not work, but restarting the port does; however, manually doing this every time is a bit tedious as well

Additional note:
In my old PC, the speakers still worked after sleep mode if I used a very specific USB port, but this does not seem to be the case with my new PC. No idea why that was.

Can workaround 3 be automated to run after sleep mode (or is there an even better solution)?

Since you're already using Uwe Sieber's USB Device Tree Viewer, there's also RestartUSBPort for the command line: https://www.uwe-sieber.de/misc_tools_e.html#restartusbport
If your computer's BIOS settings include USB power delivery in softoff/standby then you should try that. The ultimate solution is likely to replace the speakers.
Using the Windows System event log, you could try to run an automated task when Kernel-Power logs Event ID 107 (entering standby is Event ID 42). Or just put a link on the desktop (the required admin privileges trigger an annoying UAC request though).

I created a .bat file with the command and added a shortcut for it in order to assign a keyboard command/shortcut for it. But the keyboard command does not work - do you know why? I set the shortcut to run as admin...
